# Expandable subfile issue

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have written the below expandable subfile program where there seems to be an issue that causes it to not work properly once the Position to feature is used to position to a particular record. Once the display is positioned to a particular record, the program does not seem to detect Pagedown/Page up key presses anymore. No clue why. If the position to feature is not used, the paging works as expected. I don't think that the Display file DDS has an issue and hence not posting it.

```
HOPTION(*NODEBUGIO)
 FSFLTBL    IF   E           K DISK    Rename(SFLTBL:SFLTBLR)

 FSFLDSPF   CF   E             WorkStn SFILE(SFLRCD:RRN1)
 F                                     INFDS(INFO)

 DInfo             DS
 DCfKey                  369    369

 DExit             C                   Const(X'33')
 DCancel           C                   Const(X'3C')
 DEnter            C                   Const(X'F1')
 DRollUp           C                   Const(X'F5')
 DSflPag           C                   Const(15)

 DLstRrn           S              4  0 Inz(0)
 DI                S              4  0 Inz(0)

  /Free
     Exsr Clear_Subfile;
     Exsr Build_Subfile;

     Dou (*Inkc or *InKl);
       Write Footer;
       Exfmt SFLCTLRCD;
       Select;

         When (CfKey = Enter and Ptname <> *Blanks);
           Setll (PtName) Sfltbl;
           Exsr Clear_Subfile;
           Exsr Build_Subfile;
           Clear PtName;

         When (CfKey = Rollup and Not *In32);
           Exsr Build_Subfile;
       EndSl;



     EndDo;

     *Inlr = *On;

     BegSr Clear_Subfile;
       Rrn1   = *Zero;
       LstRrn = *Zero;
       *In31 = *On;
       Write SFLCTLRCD;
       *In32 = *Off;
       *In31 = *Off;
       *In90 = *Off;
     EndSr;

     BegSr Build_Subfile;

       Rrn1 = LstRrn;
       For i = 1 to SflPag;

         Read Sfltblr;
         If %Eof();
           *In90 = *On;
           Leave;
         Else;
           Rrn1 += 1;
           Write SFLRCD;
         EndIf;


       EndFor;
         If (Rrn1 > 0);
           *In32 = *Off;
         EndIf;

         LstRrn = Rrn1;
     EndSr;
  /End-Free
```

DSPF DDS below:

```
A*%%TS  SD  20170914  151431  THEJU112    REL-V5R3M0  5722-WDS                        
A*%%EC                                                                                
A                                      DSPSIZ(24 80 *DS3)                             
A                                      PRINT                                          
A                                      ERRSFL                                         
A                                      CA03                                           
A                                      CA12                                           
A          R SFLRCD                    SFL                                            
A            FNAME     R        O  5  2REFFLD(SFLTBL/FNAME *LIBL/SFLTBL)              
A            MNAME     R        O  5 24REFFLD(SFLTBL/FNAME *LIBL/SFLTBL)              
A            LNAME     R        O  5 46REFFLD(SFLTBL/FNAME *LIBL/SFLTBL)              
A          R SFLCTLRCD                 SFLCTL(SFLRCD)                                 
A*%%TS  SD  20170914  151431  THEJU112    REL-V5R3M0  5722-WDS                        
A                                      SFLSIZ(0016)                                   
A                                      SFLPAG(0015)                                   
A                                      OVERLAY                                        
A N32                                  SFLDSP                                         
A N31                                  SFLDSPCTL                                      
A  31                                  SFLCLR    
A  90                                  SFLEND(*SCRBAR *SCRBAR)
A                                      ALARM                  
A                                      ROLLUP                 
A            RRN1           4S 0H      SFLRCDNBR              
A                                  1  2USER                   
A                                  1 69DATE                   
A                                      EDTCDE(Y)              
A                                  2 69TIME                   
A                                  4  5'FIRST NAME'           
A                                      COLOR(BLU)             
A                                      DSPATR(UL)             
A                                      DSPATR(RI)             
A                                  4 28'MIDDLE NAME'          
A                                      COLOR(BLU)             
A                                      DSPATR(UL)             
A                                      DSPATR(RI)             
A                                  4 49'LAST NAME'            
A                                      COLOR(BLU)             
A                                      DSPATR(UL)             
A                                      DSPATR(RI)                  
A                                  1 24'EXPANDABLE SUBFILE'        
A                                      COLOR(RED)                  
A                                  3  6'Position To...'            
A            PTNAME        20   I  3 21                            
A          R FOOTER                                                
A                                 23  2'F3 = Exit'                 
A                                 23 16'F12 = Previous'
```

Comment: Need DDS to make sense of the indicators.

Comment: What do you mean by "the program does not seem to detect Pagedown/Page up key presses"? Are you trying to roll past the end of the subfile? Pagedown/Page up do not cause the terminal to return to the program unless it is at the end of the subfile, and you have the keyword specified.

Comment: DDS now included. What I mean is that once I position to a particular record, pressing Page up should display the top of the subfile right? The control would not return to the program in this case as there is no ROLLDOWN keyword but shouldn't the OS do it? Also, suppose if I position to the topmost record from somewhere below, page down does not seem to work. In this case, I expect the control to return back to the program. But it does not.

Comment: You said "Once the display is positioned to a particular record, the program does not seem to detect Pagedown/Page up key". But I see no explicit positioning of the subfile occurring in your RPG source. Could you explain what you mean by "Once the display is positioned"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that part of your problem is that `SFLRCDNBR` is set to the same field that is used for the relative record number for subfile IO operations `RRN1`. So no matter what you do, when `Enter` or `Page Down` is pressed, the subfile will always reposition to the last record written to `SFLRCD`.

Ok, that's one issue, but here is another issue:

```
When (CfKey = Enter and Ptname <> *Blanks);
  Setll (PtName) Sfltbl;
  Exsr Clear_Subfile;
  Exsr Build_Subfile;
  Clear PtName;
```

When you position the subfile on `Ptname`, you are clearing out the subfile, so there is nothing to roll back to. instead of clearing the subfile, you should read through the subfile until you find the correct record, and then set the `SFLRCDNBR` field to that value. You may also want to specify `SFLRCDNBR(*TOP)` in your DDS, and ensure that you have a full page in the subfile after that record.

Note: `SFLRCDNBR` can at times be a bit difficult to handle as it can not use conditioning indicators, and may not be an invalid value (i.e. it must have a value between 1 and the number of records in the subfile). So on every write to the subfile control format you need to know exactly which record needs to be the first subfile record on the display (If you are using `*TOP`), or at least one of the records on the display.

You can use a sub-procedure to locate a record in a loaded subfile. Subfile records can be read with a `CHAIN rrn` where rrn is a relative record number. So as long as I know how many records I have written to the subfile, I can loop through them with a `for` loop. Once I have found the record I am searching for, I return from the procedure and pass back the record number that I just read. That will be the relative record number of the record I found in the subfile.

```
dcl-proc FindNameInSubfile;
  dcl-pi *n Int(5) 
    PtName     Char(20) const;
  end-pi;

  dcl-ds sflds     LikeRec(sflrcd: *input) Inz;

  dcl-s ix    Int(5) Inz(0);

  for ix = 1 to maxrrn;
    chain ix sflrcd sflds;
    if sflds.lastname = PtName;
      return ix;
    endif;
  endfor;

  return -1;
end-proc;
```

This sub-procedure returns -1 if the subfile record is not found. To use this to set `sflrcdnbr` you would want to do something like this:

```
When (CfKey = Enter and Ptname <> *Blanks);
  sflrrn = FindNameInSubfile(Ptname);
  if sflrrn > 0;
    sflrcdnbr = sflrrn;
  endif;
  Ptname = '';
```

Note, `sflrrn` is a new work field defined as `Int(5)`, and `sflrcdnbr` is a new field (not RRN1) that is attached to the `SFLRCDNBR` DDS keyword.

Comment: Hi Murph, I am trying to insert the row number of the required record into the SFLRCDNBR field through an SQL using the Row_Number over(order by lname). SELECT ROW_NUMBER() into :Rrn1 OVER     
(order by lname)  FROM              
sfltbl  where lname = :Ptname. But this doesn't work. COuld you guide me a bit here?

Comment: Are you trying to do this while loading the subfile, or after the subfile is loaded? I wouldn't use the DB table to determine the location of the record in the subfile. I would read through the subfile to determine the subfile rrn that contains the record you are looking for.

Comment: After the subfile is loaded and when the user tries to position to a particular record. Not sure how the subfile can be read. I'm yet to do something like this. But it would be nice to understand how to use the ROW_NUMBER() function

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` has nothing to do with subfiles as it is an SQL function. Subfiles cannot be read using SQL. The `FindNameInSubfile()` procedure that I added to the answer reads the subfile though.

Comment: Hi, Mark Thanks a lot for the response. I'm almost there but have done things slightly different than how you described it. I don't understand how to associate the sflrcdnbr to the SFLRCDNBR DDS keyword. So the value returned by the Sub procedure is directly assigned to Rrn1 if a record with matching key is found. Also, Rrn1 value before calling the subprocedure is saved in savrrn variable. In case no match is found,Rrn1 is set to this value. I'm having to do this as each chain operation inside the for loop seems to be incrementing the Rrn1 value.Currently, the program seems to do what I want.

Comment: Change `A            RRN1           4S 0H      SFLRCDNBR` to `A            SFLRCDNBR      4S 0H      SFLRCDNBR`. This will assign the variable SFLRCDNBR to the keyword SFLRCDNBR, and remove the RRN1 assignment.

Comment: In addition, you should add a `dcl-s rrn1  Int(5);` and `dcl-s maxrrn  Int(5);` to the declarations to define `rrn1` and `maxrrn`.